# dplyr/purrr iterate over columns as well as rows

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I'm trying to drop (set to NA) values in 1 column, based on values in another column; and to do this over a large set of columns. The idea is to then pass the data to a plotting function, to generate different plots for different cuts of the data.

Here's a reproducible example:

```
d <- data.frame("A_agree" = sample(1:7, 20, replace=T),
                "B_agree" = sample(1:7, 20, replace=T),
                "C_agree" = sample(1:7, 20, replace=T),
                "A_change" = sample(1:5, 20, replace=T),
                "B_change" = sample(1:5, 20, replace=T),
                "C_change" = sample(1:5, 20, replace=T))
```

I've already found the following solution using base R, but it's of course slow, and I'm trying to learn more and more `dplyr`, so was wondering how to achieve this in `dplyr`

```
d.positive <- d
for (n in (c("A","B","C"))) {
  for (i in 1:nrow(d.positive)) {
    d.positive[i, paste0(n, "_agree")] <- ifelse(d.positive[i, paste0(n, "_change")] > 3,
                                                 d.positive[i, paste0(n, "_agree")],
                                                 NA)
  }
}
d.neutral <- d
for (n in (c("A","B","C"))) {
  for (i in 1:nrow(d.neutral)) {
    d.neutral[i, paste0(n, "_agree")] <- ifelse(d.neutral[i, paste0(n, "_change")] == 3,
                                                 d.neutral[i, paste0(n, "_agree")],
                                                 NA)
  }
}
d.negative <- d
for (n in (c("A","B","C"))) {
  for (i in 1:nrow(d.negative)) {
    d.negative[i, paste0(n, "_agree")] <- ifelse(d.negative[i, paste0(n, "_change")] < 3,
                                                 d.negative[i, paste0(n, "_agree")],
                                                 NA)
  }
}
```

I thought I would use `gather()`, and then check for each row whether the corresponding column (hence the `!!dimension`) is bigger than a certain value (`3` in this case), but it doesn't seem to work?

```
d %>%
  gather(dimension,
         value,
         paste0(c("A","B","C"), "_agree")
         ) %>%
  case_when(!!dimension > 3 ~ value=NA)
```

Alternatively, I thought I'd use `map2_dfr` from `purrr`, but I don't think it iterates over cells, just takes the entire column, hence this doesn't work:

```
map2_dfr(.x = d %>%
                 select( paste0(c("A","B","C"), "_agree") ),
         .y = d %>%
                 select( paste0(c("A","B","C"), "_change") ),
         ~ if_else(.y > 3, x, NA)} )
```

Any pointers would be really helpful, to keep learning about the wonderful world of `dplyr` !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get that you want to learn about `purrr`, but base `R` is just easier here:

```
d.positive <- d  

check  <- d.positive[4:6] <= 3 #it's the same condition
d.positive[,1:3][check] <- NA

> d.positive
   A_agree B_agree C_agree A_change B_change C_change
1        1      NA      NA        4        3        2
2        2       2      NA        4        5        2
3        4      NA      NA        4        3        1
4        1      NA      NA        4        1        2
5       NA       1      NA        2        4        1
6       NA       7      NA        3        5        1
7       NA       6      NA        1        5        1
8       NA       6       4        2        5        5
9        4      NA      NA        4        1        2
10       1      NA      NA        5        1        2
11      NA      NA      NA        3        1        2
12      NA      NA      NA        1        3        3
13      NA      NA      NA        1        1        1
14      NA      NA      NA        3        2        3
15       1      NA      NA        5        3        3
16       2      NA      NA        4        3        2
17      NA      NA       6        1        1        4
18      NA      NA      NA        1        1        2
19      NA      NA      NA        2        3        1
20      NA      NA      NA        1        3        1
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use `tidyr` package in combination with `dplyr`. In it there are new functions `pivot_longer` and `pivot_wider` which replace older `gather` and `spread`.

Using a combination of both the solution could be as follows:

```
d.neutral1 = 
  d %>% 
  mutate(row = row_number() ) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-row, names_sep = "_", names_to = c("name","type") ) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = type, values_from = value) %>% 
  mutate(result = if_else(change == 3, agree, NA_integer_))
```

and if you want a similar shape to the original

```
d.neutral1 %>% 
  select(-agree, -change) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = result)
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing to pivot_longer/wider, hadn't realised yet that gather/spread had been replaced. Great solution this also